# Anomaly using numPy datetime64 to work with dates in a pandas Dataframe column

Tags: pandas, numpy, python-3.7, datetime64

Cannot covert 'YYYY-MM' string to YYYY-MM datetime using datetime64 for data in pandas DataFrame.

np.datetime64 works to convert date string(s) of 'YYYY-MM' to datetime when stored in a scalar or array, but not when same data is accessed via a DateFrame.

What I want to do is convert a column dates (format: YYYY-MM) to datetime data (with or without adding another column).

csv file data:

```
month, volume
2019-01, 100
2019-02, 110
```

Sample Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.read_csv (r'file location')
df["date"]=df["month"].apply(np.datetime64)

# Input (month): 2013-01
# Expected output (date): 2013-01
# Actual output (date): 2013-01-01
```

So, the datetime64 changes YYYY-MM to YYYY_MM-01
(Also, YYYY is converted to YYYY-01-01)

Comment: what are you then trying to do with you `date` column. This is how pandas represents datetimes

Comment: all i'm trying to do is import a file with monthly figures from csv (or excel) file.  So, 2019-01, 100 {first row} would be the monthly volume for January, 2019.  In order to perform further operations, I though it would be best to have dates in datetimes.  What is the best practice for dates (monthly, yearly) in pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're looking for pd.Period:

```
In [11]: df.date.apply(pd.Period, freq='M')
Out[11]:
0   2019-01
1   2019-02
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Similarly, but without the apply:

```
In [12]: pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.to_period(freq='M')
Out[12]:
0   2019-01
1   2019-02
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks.  I now understand that I need to convert my data into panda date period objects.  Am I to use datetime rather than datetime64?  I'm still unable to convert my file data (YYYY-MM) in a period objects that I can perform operations, such as incrementing date by x months, etc.

Comment: @max i think it depends what you're doing, usually datetime64 is sufficient.